# PowerBI - expending json Record column with inconsistent key values

Tags: powerbi

I have a powerBI dataset with below Structure:

```
| Id | CaseName | CaseData
| 01 | Case11   | `Record`
| 02 | Case21   | `Record`
| 03 | Case31   | `Record`
```

CaseData column `Records` are in below format

```
{"Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2", ...}
{"Key1":"Value21", "Key9":"Value29", ...}
```

Keys are inconsistent across all the records. Is there any way I can expend above data to get below result using M query in the powerBI:

```
| Id | CaseName | Key  | Value
| 01 | Case11   | Key1 | value1
| 01 | Case11   | Key2 | value2
| 01 | Case12   | Key1 | value21
| 01 | Case12   | Key9 | value29
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `Record.ToTable(...)` first, then expand.

For example, you can update your column with:

```
recordToTable = Table.TransformColumns(#"Previous Step", {"CaseData", each Record.ToTable(_)})
```